# Irreducible components of normal cone $C_{X/Y}$ dominates X?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Assume $X$ is a subscheme of $Y$ and $X,Y$ are irreducible.
Then every irreducible component of the normal cone $C_{X/Y}$ dominates $X$?

Comment: That is not true.  Let $A$ be affine $3$-space, $\text{Spec}\ k[s,t,u]$.  Let $Y$ be the singular quadric surface, $\text{Spec}\ k[s,t,u]/\langle su-t^2\rangle$.  Let $X$ be a line in the surface, $\text{Spec}\ k[s,t,u]/\langle s,t \rangle$.  Then the normal cone $C_{X/\mathbb{A}^3}$ is the $\mathbb{A}^2$-bundle over the line $\text{Spec}\ (k[s,t,u]/\langle s,t \rangle)[S,T]$.  The closed subscheme $C_{X/Y}$ is $\text{Spec}\ (k[s,t,u]/\langle s,t \rangle)[S,T]/\langle uS \rangle$.  So one component, $\text{Zero}(S)$, dominates, but the other component, $\text{Zero}(u)$, does not dominate.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Another question. Is there any good theorem, paper, book about how irreducible components of normal cone behaves? Sorry for my question is not precise.

Comment: Fulton's book "Intersection Theory" has some discussion of these issues.  I do not know a definitive reference for irreducible components of the normal cone.

Comment: The only easy statement seems to be that $C_{X/Y}$ is set-theoretically equidimensional, and connected in codimension $1$, being a flat degeneration of $Y$.